# ScrollView collapsing GridViews

Tags: android, xml, gridview, scrollview

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Test">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                .../>
            <TextView
                .../>
        </LinearLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_matrici"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                .../>
            <TextView
                .../>
        </LinearLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_soluzioni"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

when I add the ScrollView the GridView are collapsed, showing only one row.

I tried them all but I can not solve the problem.

Can you tell me what to do?

Thanks in advance!

(It says that it looks like my post is mostly code, but what else can I say? The code explain all the problem!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Change `ScrollView`, `LinearLayout` (which is direct child of ScrollView) height to `wrap_content`

Add this class in your project:

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Include it in your layout like this:

```
<com.example.ExpandableHeightGridView
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
```

Lastly you just need to ask it to expand:

```
mAppsGrid = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
mAppsGrid.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: can you share screenshot?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail like: 1. There are two gridview, you are seeing only row of which gridview. 2. Are you able to scroll?

Comment: If I use ScrollView I can scroll the GridViews but they are both collapsed in one row. If I use NestedScrollView I cannot scroll and they are still collapsed. If I remove "<ScrollView.../>" I can see the GridViews extended...

Comment: no, it is the same. Have you tried to re-create this layout and in your configuration it works?

Comment: If I change ScrollView height to match_parent then I can see the GridViews extended but scrolling not works..

Comment: I tried it but I get this error: Error inflating class com.example.ExpandableHeightGridView